# Insert multimedia videos?

Tags: org-mode, video, enriched-mode

Without physically inserting videos that reside in `./Videos directory` and instead use `MPV player` or another Unix video player and make it show embedded in the same document like html web page.

Emacs should read videos from the directory location instead of working as a native player which is impossible to achieve.

I'd like to see `rich multimedia content`. If not possible to play the video `in the same window` then it should at least show the image and after clicking it should open in another window the media content.

If it can't be done I'd be upset.

Comment: If you compile Emacs with GTK3 and the X Widget library enabled (`--with-xwidgets`), then I imagine it's possible to embed a player in a buffer.

Comment: The current structure of XWidgets requires you to write extra C code for each new widget.